# Cross Document Messaging - post objects feature check FF3.6

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, postmessage

I am talking between a window and an inserted iFrame, using cross domain messaging.  The code below is the iframe talking back to the parent window.

```
sendToParent = function (event, response) {
        // send to parent
        event.source.postMessage(response.data, event.origin);
        //sent
        consolePrint('Sent: ' + response.data);
    }
```

and response.data could be string or object.

String is fine, but FF3.6 doesn't like Objects.  So we will need to stringyify the object, not a problem.

The problem we have is feature checking FF3.6 for the lack of object cross document messaging support... we really don't want to go down the road of user Agent strings, and individual device clauses.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to always serialize objects to JSON at this point. Not only it is difficult to know which browser supports objects and which doesn't but even for browsers that seem to support objects it may not be completely consistent across all of them.